# convert german umlaut with a bash one-liner using php

Tags: php, macos, bash, encoding, utf-8

Does anyone know why this just gives me an `?` instead of a german `ä`?

```
me$: php -r 'echo html_entity_decode("&auml;");'
```

The `&` for instance works well. The locale settings are:

```
LANG="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I am using bash on a Mac.

Comment: Interestingly, it works for me with `en_US.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
php -r 'echo html_entity_decode("&auml;",ENT_COMPAT,"UTF-8");'
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php